# Rudimentary Pandas syntax and operators in Dataframes for a beginner

Tags: python, pandas

I'm very new to python, I've had some experience with R-studio and MATLAB and I'm currently learning about basic Pandas coding.

The issue I'm having is searching for a specific value when given two conditions:

For instance let's say I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

data_1 =  {'name': ['Mary', 'David', 'Jack', 'John', 'Robin'],
        'Assignment 1': [99.2, 87.4, 55.3, 77.7, 61.6],
        'Assignment 2': [76.4, 65.4, 90.3, 83.5, 55.6],
          'Exam': [87.6, 59.8, 99.6, 79.4, 30.7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_1)

assessment_name = 'Final Exam'
student_name = 'John'

assessment_score = '???'
```

I want to find the following information:
I want to look for a `student_name` and an `assessment_name`, and then store this student's score for this assessment in `assessment_score`.
I have tried many things, and I know it's probably rudimentary... but I cant quite grasp the syntax for this situation.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

How about this with the `.loc` command:

```
df.loc[df['name'] == student_name, assessment_name]
```